# Why can't I access my database from the Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb, and my database is stored in /data/db (I can physically check and see it there)

Now when I start mongod,

```
$mongod --dbpath /data/db
```

I get this:

```
2014-11-08T14:15:05.376-0500 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=688 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Bill-Cosby.local
2014-11-08T14:15:05.377-0500 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4 
2014-11-08T14:15:05.377-0500 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
2014-11-08T14:15:05.377-0500 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimavericks.local 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64     BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2014-11-08T14:15:05.377-0500 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2014-11-08T14:15:05.377-0500 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
2014-11-08T14:15:05.378-0500 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2014-11-08T14:15:05.378-0500 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2014-11-08T14:15:05.410-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-11-08T14:16:05.464-0500 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:49 virt:3060
2014-11-08T14:16:05.464-0500 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):576
2014-11-08T14:16:05.464-0500 [clientcursormon]  connections:0
```

Now if I try to open a mongo shell:

```
$mongo

MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
connecting to: test
```

But if I try

```
> show dbs

admin  (empty)
local  0.078GB
```

I checked

```
db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts").parsed.storage.dbPath

/usr/local/var/mongodb
```

I checked that folder, and there are just empty folders inside of it.  But if I look in /data/db, I can see my database, with the correct size.  Anyone have ideas on how I can access my database?  I know I must be doing something stupid, as I had it working yesterday, but everytime I restart mongo it becomes a chore to get everything working again, and it seems like a different issue arises each time.

When I try

```
ps -A | grep mongod

258 ??         1:37.25 /usr/local/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
2786 ttys000    0:00.08 mongod --dbpath /data/db
2788 ttys001    0:00.00 grep mongod
```

Comment: Are you sure you are always starting the mongod with the --dbpath all the time? In the startup log lines I see the dbpath as /data/db, contradicting what's reported from the mongo shell. What happens to the data files if you insert a document in a new database?

Comment: This is why I'm confused.  Shouldn't the mongo shell be recognizing where I've set my dbpath (and accessing data from that path), or am I mistaken?  I just tried to insert a document into a new database, and I can't find the file with that data anywhere...

And yes, I always start mongod with --dbpath /data/db

Comment: The mongo shell doesn't know anything about the dbpath - it's used by the mongod process. What happens if you switch to a new database and add a document to a collection? What happens to the files in /data/db? I don't know why your mongo shell would report the wrong dbpath unless you are not connected to the mongod process you think you are.

Comment: I tried switching to a new database and adding a document.  Nothing seems to happen in /data/db...  I think you're right, that I'm not connected to the mongod process I want to be.  Do you have any idea why that is, or how I would go about connecting to the correct mongod process such that I can access my data?




Edit: Apparently, for my local.0 and local.ns data files, their "date modified" is updated whenever I exit the mongod process.

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing you installed with a package manager and it setup a mongod running in the background - the confusing thing is why there isn't a conflict on the ports. Check `ps -A | grep mongod`.

Comment: Ok I did that, and I've edited the above to show the output.  What is that showing?

Comment: hey. `ps` shows you the currently running processes on your machine. Il you combine it with a `grep`, it will filter on the parameter (here, "mongod")

Comment: the last line is the process that made the grep you just made, so ignore it. But there are two line remaining, so two mongod processes running at the same time!

Answer (score 1):

though it's a old question, Just answering for new visitors:

1. to see all databases `show dbs`

> ```
> > show dbs
> admin   0.000GB
> config  0.000GB
> local   0.000GB
> m201    0.011GB
> ```

2. connect to your database `use local`
3. to query your data base `db.startup_log.count()`

Here **db** refers to current database which is in use. In our case, current database is **local**, there is a collection named **startup_log** in local database and we are getting the count of all the documents.